# How can I make Gurobi (Using R) show all solutions

Tags: r, gurobi

As the question states: I know there are several solutions (see output of GA and check that value and constraints are correct), but I can't get them out of Gurobi.

**Edit after @Paleo13's answer**: As he states, his answer is a good workround. However I would also love to see, if there is a more efficient option. Therefore, I added a bounty. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49734762/5784831) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49746686/5784831) for what I know.

Reproducible example:

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  f <- sum(model$obj * x)
  penalty <- sum(abs(model$A %*% x - model$rhs))
  return_value <- -f - 1e8 * penalty # sum(model$obj^2) * // 1e7 * 
  return(return_value)
}

model <- structure(
  list(modelsense = "min", 
           obj = c(0, 40, 20, 40, 0, 20, 20, 20, 0), 
           A = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                           1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 
                           0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                         .Dim = c(7L, 9L), 
                         .Dimnames = list(
                           c("constraint1", "constraint2", "", "", "", "", ""), 
                           NULL)),
           rhs = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
           sense = c("=", "=", "=", "=", "=", "=", "="), 
           vtype = "B"), 
      .Names = c("modelsense", "obj", "A", "rhs", "sense", "vtype"))

# Gurobi:
params <- list(OutputFlag = 1, Presolve = 2,  LogToConsole = 1, PoolSearchMode = 2, PoolSolutions = 10)
ilp_result <- gurobi::gurobi(model, params)
print(ilp_result$x)

# GA for cross-check
GA <- GA::ga(type = "binary", fitness = my_fun, nBits = length(model$obj),
             maxiter = 3000, run = 2000, popSize = 10, seed = 12)

# Crosscheck:
summary(GA)

my_fun(ilp_result$x)
my_fun(GA@solution[1, ])
my_fun(GA@solution[2, ])

sum(abs(model$A %*% ilp_result$x - model$rhs))
sum(abs(model$A %*% GA@solution[1, ] - model$rhs))
sum(abs(model$A %*% GA@solution[2, ] - model$rhs))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe can be done with the [Solution Pool](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/solution_pool.html).  Gurobi added the R API for the solution pool in version 8.0.  You [set parameters](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/finding_multiple_solutions.html) to control the solution pool; the multiple solutions are returned in the [Solution Pool named components](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/gurobi.html).  This is illustrated in the [poolsearch.R example](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/examples/poolsearch_r.html), which can also be found in the examples\R subdirectory.

Disclaimer: I manage technical support for Gurobi.

Comment: Try increasing PoolGap.

Comment: Double-check that you didn't modify the data as well as check the LP file that gets generated from this sample.  I definitely get 21 solutions when I tested it from the original data.

Comment: Everything working, really cool! (I forgot to install version 8.0 - sorry, really stupid). Perhaps you can add [this link](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/examples/poolsearch_r.html) to your answer?

Comment: Thanks again! Perhaps you also know, whether somethink linke [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49734762/5784831) is already implemented in Gurobi 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

*Gurobi* can indeed store feasible solutions it that encounters while searing for the optimal solution (or rather a solution that fits within a specified opitmality gap). These solutions are stored in a "solution pool". Unfortunately, the *gurobi R* package does not have the functionality to access the solutions in the solution pool, so if we are looking for a solution that just uses *R* then we cannot use the solution pool. Also, it's worth noting that the solution pool may not necessarily contain all the feasible solutions, it only contains the solutions that *Gurobi* found along the way, so if we require all the feasible solutions then we cannot just rely on the solution pool in a single run of *Gurobi*.

So, with regards to your question, one strategy is to use a method referred to as "Bender's cuts". This basically involves solving the problem, adding in constraints to forbid the solution we just obtained, and then solving the problem again, and repeating this process until there aren't any more feasible solutions. I have written a function that implements this method using the *gurobi R* package below and applied it to your example. This method may not scale very well to problems with a large number of feasible solutions, because ideally we would access the solution pool to reduce the total number of *Gurobi* runs, but this is the best approach to my knowledge (but I would love to hear if anyone has any better ideas).

```
# define functions
find_all_feasible_solutions <- function(model, params) {
  # initialize variables
  counter <- 0
  solutions <- list()
  objs <- numeric(0)
  # search for feasible solutions until no more exist
  while (TRUE) {
    # increment counter
    counter <- counter + 1
    # solve problem
    s <- gurobi::gurobi(model, params)
    # break if status indicates that no feasible solution found
    if (s$status %in% c("INFEASIBLE")) break()
    # store set of solutions
    solutions[[counter]] <- s$x
    objs[[counter]] <- s$objval
    # add constraint to forbid solution this solution
    model$rhs <- c(model$rhs, sum(s$x) - 1)
    model$sense <- c(model$sense, "<=")
    model$A <- rbind(model$A, (s$x * 2) - 1)
  }
  # throw error if no feasible sets of solutions found
  if (length(solutions) == 0) {
    stop("no feasible solutions found.")
  }
  # return solutions as matrix
  list(x = do.call(rbind, solutions), obj = objs)
}

# create initial model
model <- list(
  modelsense = "min",
   obj = c(0, 40, 20, 40, 0, 20, 20, 20, 0),
   A = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
     1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0,
     0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    .Dim = c(7L, 9L),
    .Dimnames = list(c("constraint1", "constraint2", "", "", "", "", ""),
                     NULL)),
  rhs = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  sense = c("=", "=", "=", "=", "=", "=", "="),
  vtype = "B")

# create parameters
params <- list(OutputFlag = 1, Presolve = 2,  LogToConsole = 1)

# find all feasible solutions
output <- find_all_feasible_solutions(model, params)

# print number of feasible solutions
print(length(output$obj))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Let's see, if there is anything faster. Perhaps you are intersted in [this](https://github.com/jeffreyhanson/rgurobi). But there might be a problem with rtools, see closed issue: "... It turns out that Gurobi cannot be compiled using the GCC toolchain on Windows (http://www.gurobi.com/products/supported-platforms), so I guess this means that this package can't be compiled using rtools."

Comment: The R API for the solution pool was added in version 8.0.